# Assigning array new values from another array of different size

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

```
import numpy as np
from math import *
import pandas as pd
prob = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.02,0.04,0.005,0.4,0.5,0.9,1.0])
con = np.array([1,100,10,50,60,70,30])
new = np.array(map(dict(zip(sorted(prob),sorted(con))).get,prob))
print new
[50 60 70 10 30 1 100 None None None]
```

I am trying to assign new values to my prob array using the con values. But there are less con values than prob values. I am wondering if it is possible to assign a con value to a prob value more than once? For example, I would want the output to look something like:

```
[30 30 50 1 1 1 50 60 70 100]
```

If not possible, would I just need to write a condition?

Comment: Why are you using numpy arrays to immediately call`list()` on the result? Also, perhaps opinion-based, `list(map(dict(zip(sorted(` is getting a little out of hand from a clear understanding perspective :)

Comment: Well all you need to decide is what values from `con` do you want to go with the unassigned values in `prob`. Do you simply want to repeat `con` again so that its `[1,100,10,50,60,70,30,1, 100, 10]` or do you want to repeat the last value `[1,100,10,50,60,70,30,30,30,30]` or sample some random values?

Comment: @ALollz I want the maximum prob value to be assigned the maximum con value, and the minimum prob value assigned the minimum con value and the next highest prob value assigned the next highest con value and so on. So I would want the output to look something like [30,30,50,1,1,1,50,60,70,100]

Comment: @Mary Could you separate the `prob` in two parts: one the same size of `con` with values corresponding to `con`, and the other one for the value you want to add? I think it would be much clearer...